# How to change per_process_gpu_memory_fraction in tensorflow using c++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, memory-management, gpu

I have develop two applications based on tf in c++ language, these applications are served as libraries. In the caller execuable program, library1 is called then library2. In library1 initialization,  gpu memory fraction is set to 0.5, run some inference, and session closed. then library2 is called, gpu memory fraction is set to 0.8, but the setting can not work, gpu memory allocation did not change. Both library have the same initialization code but differnet fraction value

```
int XXXLib::init(double per_process_gpu_memory_fraction)
{
    SessionOptions options;
    ConfigProto* config = &options.config;
    GPUOptions* gpu_options = config->mutable_gpu_options();

    // for library1, fraction = 0.5; for library2, fraction = 0.8
    gpu_options->set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction);
    Status status = NewSession(options, &_session);
}
```

It seems that when set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction() is called, the gpu memory in this process is fixed, even new another Newsession(), the original fraction value is used.

1. Should different app(library) use different session ?
2. gpu memory fraction is related to session or to process ?
3. How  to change the fraction in different session but the same process?

Some env info:

- Have I written custom code? NO
- OS Platform and Distribution? Win10 Pro
- TensorFlow installed from? Source code
- TensorFlow version? 1.9
- CUDA/cuDNN version? CUDA9.0, cudnn 7.05
- GPU model and memory? GTX1080 with 8GB memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunate, but in the current TensorFlow (1.11) the GPU memory allocator is created once (per GPU device) - the first time a session is created in the process. Changing `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` in the following sessions will not have any effect.

In regards to your library, I would suggest not creating sessions inside it. Ask the user to provide you a session that they configure as they wish. Alternatively, you can just create a graph and return the operations to run. The user can then run them as they see fit.

Comment: If ask user to config and provide session, it still doesn't work when 2nd calling set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(), or you means to combine two libraries to one, they have only one interface to create session?

Comment: Yeah, refactoring the code will not magically make set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction per-session. I was just suggesting that Session configuration is a very high-level concept that should generally be handled by the end user, not deep in the library...  The only real way to allocate different amounts of GPU memory is to start a new process.